# my outlinebutton button does not execute the onPressed event - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

```
          Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: screenHeidth,
              width: screenWidth,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage("assets/fondo1.png"),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, right: 20.0),
                child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                    child: OutlineButton(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30.0),

                      onPressed: () {
                        print("press");
                        Navigator.push(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Safe()));
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        "SALTAR",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.white, style: BorderStyle.solid),
                      shape: StadiumBorder(),
                    )),
              ),
            ),
],
        );
```

I am a little worried it cost me something to put this design .. And now it turns out that my little button does not execute the action that I need, the other parts of the code I am not placing it if necessary I could add some photo of the design

Comment: is it showing some error?

Comment: It must be an ordering issue of widgets because you are using stack. Button would be behind some widget so it's onPressed isn't being called.To confirm if stack is causing the issue and items aren't ordered properly try replacing Stack with Column to check.

Answer (score 0):

Try using named routes:

On your Safe page under Stless or Stfull define a route name:

```
static const routeName = '/your-safe-page';
```

After go to your main.dart file and define this route after MaterialApp(

```
initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (ctx) => YourHomeScreen(),
        Safe.routeName: (ctx) => Safe(),
        },
```

After go again and retry with this method:

```
onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Safe.routeName);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to replicate the issue you mentioned. the `onPress` event fires properly and navigates to next screen. Sample working code below:

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/placeholder.png"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, right: 20.0),
              child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  child: OutlineButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30.0),

                    onPressed: () {
                      print("press");
                      Navigator.push(context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Safe()));
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      "SALTAR",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.white, style: BorderStyle.solid),
                    shape: StadiumBorder(),
                  )),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}

class Safe extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It prints the output in console properly:

```
I/flutter ( 4357): press
I/flutter ( 4357): press
```

You may compare your code with above and identify what you are missing from your code.

Hope this helps.